# MySQL Days Between One Order and Next Order Having > 1 Order

Tags: mysql, select, lag, datediff

My goal is to find how many customers order more than once between the criteria below. Or to put into other terms, how long it takes for customers to place their **next** order with these criteria:

- 0 - 12 mos
- 13 - 24 mos
- 25 - 36 mos
- 37+ mos

Table is set up by line item on each order. like this:

```
Customer | Item  | OrderNumber | OrderDate
1500       item1   5555          2015-02-01
1500       item2   5555          2015-02-01
1500       item34  5255          2014-05-25
1500       item44  4100          2012-12-30
2200       item55  5100          2014-02-15
2200       item1   5100          2014-02-15
3255       item12  5300          2015-03-05
3255       item34  5399          2014-05-01
3255       item22  5399          2014-05-01
```

So if it takes less than 12 mos for a customer to order more than once then it should be counted towards the "0-12 mos".  If a customer took 18 mos to place their next order they would be counted towards the "13-24 mos" and so on and so forth.

I don't really know where to begin on this one.  I probably will have to at least have: `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT OrderNumber) > 1`.  I have never used `LAG`, is this something that I should utilize a MySQL variant of to find the next `OrderDate` in the sequence?

Any help would be appreciated to at least start to identify the components of the query needed.

Comment: Do you want customers to count more than once?  Or are you looking at the *average* between orders?  What about the last order; is that included?

Comment: Could you just provide expected result table for the raw data you posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just wanted the average time between orders, you can do something like this:

```
select floor(days_between / 365) as numyears, count(*)
from (select customer, datediff(max(orderdate), min(orderdate)) as days_between
             count(*) as numorders
      from orders
      group by customer
      having count(*) >= 2
     ) c
group by numyears;
```

If you really want to understand the timing between orders, learn about survival analysis, particularly recurrent event analysis.  Your question, although well-enough formed, is rather naive because it does not consider customers with only one order nor the time since a customer's last order.

Comment: All very good points.  When determining Lifetime Value we want to understand how long it takes for customers to order more than once. When they order more than once, they are now figured as "retained". Unfortunately I believe there are quite a few ways we can spin this into weird metrics

Comment: @ToddN . . . My suspicion.  Learn about survival and recurrent event analysis.  It is designed for exactly what you want to do, and you can probably do everything you need to do in SQL.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, in order to get exact I will need to learn about that.  But in the mean time the query you provided does suffice.